# wget not downloading index.html located in sub folder

Tags: linux, macos, download, terminal, wget

I'm trying to download an offline version of the PhantomJS documentation.

I'm running the following command :

```
wget -p -k -r -l 0 -e robots=off -U Mozilla http://phantomjs.org

-p   : to get all required elements/files (css, js, images...)
-k   : to convert the links for offline browsing
-r   : recursive
-l 0 : no level restriction
```

It works but the index.html page is not downloaded from the subfolder located at the following url : 
http://phantomjs.org/api/.

I have instead an "Index of" page when I visit the offline copy located : file:///path/phantomjs.org/api/

The thing is, I'm able to download the file when targeting it specifically.

```
wget http://phantomjs.org/api/
```

Any idea?

Comment: you could use the `-E` option - this produces directory `/path/phantomjs.org/api/` (with corresponding content) as well as a file `/path/phantomjs.org/api.html`. The `API` link in the main menu in `/path/phantomjs.org/index.html` then points to `/path/phantomjs.org/api.html` which contains the links to the other sections such as "Command line interface", etc.

Comment: That did the trick thanks!